# Toggle Bootstrap tab panes with <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 main tabs A and B. Each tab has 2 subtabs which are A11, A12 and B11, B22. I am triggering those subtabs with links on A and B but now i want to change the links to be select option.

I've tried doing that using javascript but when i select A shows me A11 and when i select B shows me A22 not B11.

A live example of how it looks now with trigger on links can be found [here](http://www.10plus.org/beta/cursuri.php).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ufu063p9/

Comment: edit demo again to clear your question

Comment: Please take a look at the example [here](http://www.10plus.org/beta/cursuri.php) below are 3 price tables and the tabs that i've talk about. I want to make the main tabs ELEVI CLASELE II - IV and ELEVI CLASELE V - VIII to be select option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uncomment your first tabs nav (`.nav-clase`) and hide it using `hidden` class. Then in jQuery you can use `change()` function to change tabs after option changes.

```
$('#select').change(function () {
    if($(this).val() == '0') {
    $('.nav-clase').find('[href="#clasele24"]').tab('show');
  } else {
    $('.nav-clase').find('[href="#clasele58"]').tab('show');
  }
});
```

### **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ufu063p9/1/)**

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks.